# Is it possible to use variables in a ClearCase config spec?

Tags: version-control, clearcase, wildcard, config-spec

For example, instead of writing the following:

```
element * .../my_branch_01/LATEST
element * .../base_branch/LATEST -mkbranch my_branch_01
```

I would want to write something like this:

```
MY_BRANCH=my_branch_01
element * .../%MY_BRANCH%/LATEST
element * .../base_branch/LATEST -mkbranch %MY_BRANCH%
```

Is this even possible?  What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Just tested and fixed the select rule base on an attribute: it works and let you select a branch based on its attribute value. The attribute becomes your variable. But it cannot be used for mkbranch directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only native way to do this in ClearCase is to use **attribute** within a **[config-spec](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/config_spec.htm)**.

According to the [version selector](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/version_selector.htm) rules, you can make a "selection by query" rule, based for instance on an attribute:

```
element * ...{MY_ATTRIBUTE_NAME=="aValue"}
```

would select the `LATEST` version on any branch with an attribute '`MY_ATTRIBUTE_NAME`' with '`aValue`' in it.

That mean you need to change the attribute value on the old branch, put it on the new branch, '`cleartool setcs`' your view again, and you should have a new content based on a new version selection.

Not very straight forward, but it could work, ***except for the mkbranch part*** (which needs a fixed name).

---

Regarding [GeekCyclist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680162/wildcards-or-placeholders-in-clearcase-config-specs-possible/680219#680219), a few comments:

The solution to include a common config spec can work for Base ClearCase solution, but:

- need to be in a share available by all concerned developer
- the **[setcs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setcs.htm)** is indeed necessary to Ccuses the view_server to flush its caches and reevaluate the current config spec, which is stored in file config_spec in the view storage directory. This includes:

  - Evaluating time rules with nonabsolute specifications (for example, now, Tuesday)
  - Reevaluating –config rules, possibly selecting different derived objects than previously
  - **Re-reading files named in include rules**
- all the other developers need to be notified when the common included config spec file changes (there is no native notification included in ClearCase)

---

If you need to have one "environment" (i.e. one "view" or workspace) with a variable content (depending on a different branch), you need to define a symbolic link (or a windows subst) pointing to different views (each with their own config spec)

That way, you only have to change the link (or the path subst'ed) in order to change the config spec associated with a given *fixed* path.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I worked in ClearCase (we switched to Subversion), but if I recall correctly there is no way to do this native to ClearCase.

You could use or write a script generator that would create your spec file and then include that in the actual spec:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
include scripted_file_output
```

Then run

```
cleartool setcs -current
```

The problem with this approach is that I believe the include spec would need to be regenerated and the cleartool setcs run whenever you change the value of MY_BRANCH.